# Character to Hexadecimal?

Tags: c, char, hex

I am trying to convert a Char to hex for example I have 'f' in char I want to convert it in 0xf or if I have '9' that should be converted to 0x9. 
Currently I am doing it like

```
if(char_array[i]>=0x0A)
   Hex_array[i] =( char_array[i] - 0x09) | 040;
else
   Hex_array[i] = (char_array[i] | 0x30);
```

But it only works with values below '9'.

Comment: `040` is octal...Maybe you forgot a little`x`: `0x40`

Comment: Lol yes it's 0x40. My bad

Answer (score 0):

Value `040` is octal, but your code can work with `0x40` (hexadecimal)

```
    if(char_array[i]>=0x0A)
       Hex_array[i] =( char_array[i] - 0x09) | 0x40;
    else
       Hex_array[i] = (char_array[i] | 0x30);
```

To improve the readability of code you can use char literal

```
    if ((char_array[i]>0x09) && (char_array[i]<0x10))
       Hex_array[i] =( char_array[i] - 0x0A) + 'A';
    else if ((char_array[i]>=0x00) && (char_array[i]<0x0A))
       Hex_array[i] = (char_array[i] + '0');
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be (char_array[i]<=0x0F)?